# What does 'sheers' mean in scene 2, act I of "Measure for Measure"?

Tags: meaning, william-shakespeare, measure-for-measure

In [act I, scene 2](https://internetshakespeare.uvic.ca/doc/MM_F1/scene/1.2/index.html), of *Measure for Measure*, one of the gentlemen uses the word *sheer*:

> **Luc**. I, why not? Grace, is Grace, despight of all con-,
> trouersie: as for example; Thou thy selfe art a wicked
> villaine, despight of all Grace.
>
> **First Gent**. Well: there went but a paire of ***sheeres*** be-
> tweene vs.
> **Luc**. I grant: as there may betweene the Lists, and
> the Veluet. Thou art the List.

From *[ShakespearesWords.com](https://www.shakespeareswords.com)* I gathered that *[sheers](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sheer#English)* is used here as *[shears](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shears)*, but I still cannot make any sense out of it. Why would there be any shears between soldiers? Is *sheers* just a friendly term for bladed weapon such as sword?

Comment: [This version](http://shakespeare.mit.edu/measure/full.html) has more modern spelling, and has this line as "Well, there went but a pair of shears between us."

Comment: From [A. Leggatt, "Substitution in "Measure for Measure"", *Shakespeare Quarterly* 39(3) (1988), pp. 342-359](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2870931.pdf): *"This denial of apparent resemblance is repeated in incidental touches throughout the play. The First Gentleman's "Well, there went but a pair of shears between us" is countered by Lucio's "I grant: as there may between the lists and the velvet" (I.ii.27-2)."*

Comment: *There went but a pair of shears between us* is an earlier version of the idiom *We are cut from the same cloth*. And quite a bit of wordplay follows on the same theme with *list* and *velvet*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Peter Shor has noted in the comments, the expression "There went but a pair of shears between us" means "We are cut from the same cloth". Lucio and the First Gentleman are humorously exchanging insults. Lucio calls the gentleman a wicked villain, and the gentleman counters by saying that Lucio too is cut from the same cloth: that is, Lucio is a villain as well. Lucio in turn says that there is as much difference between the gentleman and himself as there is between velvet and lists, i.e., between the unwoven bordering strips that surround the woven velvet. Those too would have had only a pair of shears between them, but velvet is valuable and the lists would have been worthless scraps of material.

Comment: And then the First Gentleman makes a pun on *3-piled velvet* (i.e., thick velvet) with *pilled/peeled* (which is slang for *bald*), and calls Lucio bald. Then, as baldness is a symptom of syphilis, he brings syphilis (the "French disease" in). But Lucio implies that the First Gentleman, since he is so well acquainted with the symptoms of syphilis, must be familiar with them first-hand, to which the First Gentleman replies "I think I haue done my selfe wrong, haue I not". And after that, it keeps going!

Comment: @PeterShor Whoever wrote this stuff seems pretty clever.